# Typescript for..of loop x numbers of times

Tags: typescript, loops

I know there a lot of answers about looping x amount of times on javascript but i'm finding if there any way to loop x amount of times in a typescript `for..of` loop function on an array, until now i haven't able to look up any answer involving the `for..of` function . Example:

```
const someArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for(let i of someArray) {
  console.log(i);
}

//loop result are from 1 to 7
//i would like the loop to run 3 times so expected result to be 1, 2, 3
```

What i'm looking for is to run the loops only `3 times` and apply to the `for...of` function of typescript

I'm still a novice at typescript

Comment: What does this have to do with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through the first elements of an array in javascript, use a standard for loop, and end the loop counter at 3:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   console.log(someArray[i])
}
```

Typescript does not change anything here, except give you the option to be explicit that the loop counter is a number.

```
for (let i: number = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   console.log(someArray[i])
}
```